Deploying a docker container to Web apps for containers Azure
Summary
I have a simple application, im using node-media-server to build a simple streaming server, and im packaging it as a container to help keep things consistent, I am trying to deploy the app through the web app for containers the app deploys successfully, and i can see that node-media-server has started as it says its "Listening for rtmp on port 1935" however, nothing i do allows me to connect to it, i cant push a stream from OBS to the server, it just fails out and says it cant connect to the server..
What i've tried
After looking around on SO for some time, some articles mention using WEBSITES_PORT to fix the issue, i've tried this, and set it to different settings like 1935, 3000 etc. I was also running into an issue where the app would fail startup because it didnt respond to http requests after a certain amount of time.. However i fixed this by adding a lightweight http server to respond to requests at / with a status of ok.. so the app works.. the api is reachable.. but i cant push a rtmp stream to the server
I do have the correct ports exposed in the Dockerfile
# Expose the necessary ports
EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 1935

im also exposing the ports in the docker-compose.. I feel like the issue is related to the fact that its a web app, and its not expecting an rtmp traffic
Code
Server.ts


import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
import apiV1Routes from "./routes/v1/apiV1Routes";
import errorHandler from "./middleware/error";
import executeGitPull from "./utils/executeGitPull";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import fs from "fs";
import morgan from "morgan";
import path from "path";
import NodeMediaServer from "node-media-server";
const ffmpegPath = require("@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg").path;
const colors = require("colors");


dotenv.config();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  app.use(morgan("dev"));
}

app.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send("API is running... ");
});

const httpConfig = {
  port: 8000,
  allow_origin: "*",
  mediaroot: "./media",
};

const rtmpConfig = {
  port: 1935,
  chunk_size: 60000,
  gop_cache: true,
  ping: 10,
  ping_timeout: 60,
  // Define the edge server cluster
  cluster: {
    master: "rtmp://media-server:1935/live",
    urls: ["rtmp://media-edge-server:1940/live"],
  },
};

const transformationConfig = {
  ffmpeg: ffmpegPath, // ffmpeg path
  tasks: [
    {
      app: "live",
      hls: true,
      hlsFlags: "[hls_time=2:hls_list_size=3:hls_flags=delete_segments]",
      // hlsKeep: true, // to prevent hls file delete after end the stream
      dash: true,
      dashFlags: "[f=dash:window_size=3:extra_window_size=5]",
      // dashKeep: true, // to prevent dash file delete after end the stream
      mp4: true,
      mp4Flags: "[movflags=frag_keyframe+empty_moov]",
    },
  ],
  mediaroot: "./media",
};

const config = {
  http: httpConfig,
  rtmp: rtmpConfig,
  trans: transformationConfig,
};

// create a server instance
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${PORT}`);
});
var nms = new NodeMediaServer(config as any);
nms.run();

nms.on("preConnect", (id, args) => {
  console.log("[NodeEvent on preConnect]", `id=${id} args=${JSON.stringify(args)}`);
  // let session = nms.getSession(id);
  // session.reject();
});
nms.on("donePublish", (id, StreamPath, args) => {
  console.log("[NodeEvent on donePublish]", `id=${id} StreamPath=${StreamPath} args=${JSON.stringify(args)}`);
  // set a timeout to delete the file after 10 seconds
  setTimeout(async () => {
    // remove the directory after the stream is done
    const file = await fs.rmSync(path.join(__dirname, "../media", StreamPath), { recursive: true });
    console.log(colors.red("Directory removed!"));
  }, 10000);
});




What Node.js version are you using?

@SirraSneha In my Dockerfile i have it set to node latest

I created a simple node-media-server application and tried deploying it to Azure Web App via Azure container registry and got the same error.

Azure App Service only supports ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS). Custom ports like 1935 for RTMP are not supported.

So, to handle the RTMP streaming we can use Azure VM or Azure Kubernetes Service.
I've used AKS to handle the RTMP streaming
Thanks to @medium.com for clear explanation. I referred to this doc and created an application using node-media-server.

After creating the application, I ran the below commands

 docker build -t <image-name> . 


Run the below commands to push the docker image to Azure container registry.

az acr login -n <container-registry>
docker tag <image-name> <container-registry>.azurecr.io/<image-name>:<tag>
docker push <container-registry>.azurecr.io/<image-name>:<tag>


Create AKS cluster in Azure portal and run the below command

az aks get-credentials --resource-group <resource-group> --name <aks-cluster-name>

Now create a Kubernetes Deployment and Service YAML Files.
deployment.yaml:
Configure your image in the deployment YAML file and specify port 1935.
<your-acr-name>.azurecr.io/vimage1:latest` 

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: rtmp-server
spec:
replicas: 1
selector:
matchLabels:
app: rtmp-server
template
metadata:
labels:
app: rtmp-server
spec:
containers:
- name: rtmp-server
image: <container-registry-name>.azurecr.io/vimage1:latest
ports:
- containerPort: 1935
- containerPort: 8000

service.yaml:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: rtmp-service
spec:
type: LoadBalancer
ports
 - name: rtmp
port: 1935
targetPort: 1935
protocol: TCP
 - name: http
port: 8000
targetPort: 8000
protocol: TCP
selector:
app: rtmp-server


Run the below commands to deploy to AKS

kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml
kubectl apply -f service.yaml


After running the command kubecti get services you will get the external IP assigned to your RTMP service.


Use rtmp://<external-ip>:1935/live as your RTMP server URL.



Now I can successfully view the video in HLS player.

